# Как получить указатель на базовый класс std::variant?

Tags: c++

У меня есть 2 класса наследуемых от третьего:

```
class Base{
  public:
    int id;
    int GetId(){return id;};  
};
class A:public Base{
};
class B:public Base{
};
```

Есть лист вариантов:

```
using EntitiesVariant = std::variant<A,B>;
std::list <EntitiesVariant> entities{};
```

Я пробегаюсь по списку, и ищу объекты с определенным id, я не знаю с каким объектом я имею дело в каждой итерации:

```
auto it = this->ServerData.entities.begin();
while (it != this->ServerData.entities.end())
{
    auto* current_base=&std::get<Base>(*it);
}
```

Но так оно не работает, потому что Base не является частью типов варианта.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял, зачем в такой ситуации вообще `variant`...

Comment: Поддержу Harry - чтобы не усложнять, не используйте `variant`, храните в списке указатели на базовый класс `std::list<Base*> entities;`

Comment: @DmitryK в таком случае прийдется реализовывать виртуальный деструктор и еще вручную заниматься уничтожением объектов

Comment: Храните `unique_ptr<>` - он за вас будет создавать/уничтожать объект. Или `shared_ptr<>/weak_ptr<>` - в зависимости от задачи. Виртуальный деструктор нужен только если вы в классе сами выделяете ресурсы, например память. Именно он и должен будет их освободить. А если уж хочется с вариантом - напишите класс-обертку, в котором будет ваш вариант, и метод возвращающий указатель на `Base`. B храните в списке объекты уже этого класса.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен `std::visit`:

```
Base *current_base = std::visit([](auto &x) -> Base * {return &x;}, *it);
```